# regex expression in javascript

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex in javascript to match a 9-digit number with these characteristics:

> First 3 digits should not be ‘0’ ,
>
> 4th and 5th Digit should not be ‘0’,
>
> Last 4 digits should not be ‘0000’,
>
> First 3 digits should not be ‘666’,
>
> Last 3 Digits Should not be greater than ‘899’

Can someone please help me out with this.

Here is my current regex:

```
/^666[^0]{3}[1-9]{2}0000$/
```

, but it’s not meeting the criteria

Comment: @lucumt i am thinking, that if we can match the last 3rd digit should not be 9 with the numbers followed by it. By it we can achieve that, but facing difficulty in building it with the above scnarios. Can you please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This regular expression it will work `^(?!(000)|(666))[0-9]{3}[1-9]{2}[0-9][0-8][0-9]{2}(?<!0000)$`. See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7cfL77/4)

Comment: it is failing if any of the 3 digits is having 6. But it should allow 6 Eg:165456789, in this scenario it needs to accept but it is failing

Answer (score 1):

Try this `^[^06]{3}[^0]{2}[^0][1-8][^0]{2}$`

Below is my explanation for it

```
First 3 digits should not be ‘0’  
First 3 digits should not be ‘666’,->  ^[^06]{3} 
4th and 5th Digit should not be ‘0’, -> [^0]{2}
Last 4 digits should not be ‘0000’, -> [^0]{4}
Last 3 Digits Should not be greater than ‘899’ -> [1-8][^0]{2}$
```

Comment: @Inder Sorry,I just take it as `Last 3 Digits Should be greater than ‘899’`, I do not pay attention to `not`

Comment: This excludes any 6 in the first 3 digits, while the requirement was that the first 3 digits should not be `666` - not the same thing. Also, the ending `[1-8][^0]{2}$` wrongfully excludes `0xx` where `x` is anything and `y00` where `y` is 0-8.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for your comment,I think the accepted answer has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Because all nine characters need to be a digit, you might use lookahead from the beginning to check that there are 9 digits followed by the end of the string, which will make the subsequent groups easier to manage. Then, you need to utilize character sets and negative lookahead. The first two conditions look to collapse together - the first five characters need to be other than 0:

```
/^(?=\d{9}$)(?!666)[^0]{5}(?!0000)\d[^9]/
```

```js
const re = /^(?=\d{9}$)(?!666)[^0]{5}(?!0000).[^9]/;
`555555555
5555555555
055555555
555505555
666555555
555550000
555550001
555550900
555550953`
  .split('\n')
  .forEach(n => console.log(re.test(String(n))));
```

Explanation:

```
555555555   true
5555555555  false; 10 digits, not 9
055555555   false: has 0 in first 5 digits
555505555   false: has 0 in first 5 digits
666555555   false: starts with 666
555550000   false: ends with 0000
555550001   true
555550900   false: sixth digit is a 9 (so last 3 digits are 9xx, which is greater than 899)
555550953   false: same as above
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vpwbk0/1